# When to use .exe and when not?

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin

I dont really understand whats going on and cant see the difference:

I'm downloaded the `base64.exe` for creating base64 text under windows. i copied it to `C:\Windows\` because its in the `%PATH%` variable.

Now i want to try it: `echo Hello | base64` works great. Okay i dont need to append `.exe` and as far as i know i dont need to do it also with `.bat` and `.com` files.

But now i have some cygwin tools installed and for example tried `which base64`, which doesnt work, because it says that `base64 is not in path`. Then i typed in `which base64.exe` and got `C:\Windows`.

So my question is now: when i need to use .exe and when i dont? Is it only when i'm using cygwin tools that i need to append .exe?

Comment: Whether or not you need to supply the file extension depends on what tool you are using.

1. You don't need to include .exe, .bat or .com when you are executing the files.
2. You do need to include it when calling `which`.

Comment: Incidentally, Windows has the "where" command, similar to "which".  And since it's a Windows tool, "where base64" will work as you might expect. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin is a shell which emulates UNIX behaviour. UNIX doesn't know anything about `.exe`, thats why Cygwin can't find `base64.exe`. Under UNIX, binaries are stored without an extionsion added to their filename, e.g. just `base64`.

Windows CMD automatically appends `.bat`, `.com`, `.exe` and the like to your file names. Cygwin does not. So if you are using a linux shell you have to append it manually.

Since Cygwin is aware that it always runs under Windows it might append `.exe` if you want to perform certain actions in the shell itself (e.g. opening a file), to behave more friendyl to Windows users who expect this behaviour. However programs running under Cygwin might not integrate those features since they were mainly devoloped for usage under UNIX. That could be a reason why `which base64` fails.

Comment: but if i run a tool under the supplied bash, it also works without the exe... so something is a little bit messed up there

Comment: Expanded my awnser. Hope that helps.